# Can I use reduce instead of a for loop?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a hashSet with 0 to X numbers and values of high integer numbers.

0:1000000001

1:1000000002

...

and a vector of positions (22,14,29,59,10).
I need to generate all combinations of this vector.
For this goal i use a library from https://github.com/mraggi/discreture to do the generation. I get all combinations of a vector size and need_comb_size 
like (10,3)

0,1,2
  0,1,3 
...

Now i link the generated combination with my vector position and hashSet like
hashSet[vect[comb[0]]+...

Can I use this in an one line with [`reduce`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce).

The goal is to generate a high integer number(hash) and use this hash as key and my positions from comb example: (12,59,11) as value.

3423422821 : vector ((12,59,11) <-- positions, (3,19,299,490) <-- dimensions). If a comb has the same signature in any dimension, this dimension will be add.

```
void combination(int size, vector<unsigned short> chunk, vector<unsigned long long> hashSet, unordered_map<unsigned long long, pair<vector<unsigned short>, vector<unsigned short>>> collision_map, unsigned long long low, unsigned long long high, int dimension) {
    for (auto&& comb : discreture::combinations_stack(size,KCOMB))
    {
        unsigned long long signature = 0;
        vector<unsigned short> newChunk;
        //signature = reduce(std::execution::par, comb.begin(), comb.end())
        for (auto v : comb) {
            signature += hashSet.at(chunk.at(v));
            newChunk.push_back(chunk.at(v));
        }
        checkSignature(low, high, signature, collision_map, newChunk, dimension);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that `std::reduce` has the caveat

> The behavior is non-deterministic if `binary_op` is not associative or not commutative.

If you care about the order of elements in `newChunk`, then you can't use `reduce` in the inner loop.

If you care about the order of calls to `checkSignature`, then you can't use `reduce` in the outer loop, and otherwise you still have to synthesise a value to throw away at the end, as you can't pass a `void` as the accumulator.